# Selection of Popup Button clearing UI Text Field

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nspopupbutton

I've been developing a programming where the user can select a list of fields from popup buttons, then they press a calculate button and then depending on the choices, a string of text gets outputted to a UIText Field.

However I would like for the text field to be cleared when the user starts selecting other choices in the popup button before pressing the select button.

Is there anyway this is possible?

Comment: Can't you just write this code: theTextYouAreTalkingAbout.text = ""

Answer (score 0):

Just right this code in the place where that happens:

```
/*You can replace theTextFieldYouAreTalkingAbout with the one you are talking about*/

theTextFieldYouAreTalkingAbout.text = ""
```